# can't connect to samba share folder from ubuntu to windows

Tags: networking, server, windows, samba, shared-folders

I want to create a share folder from my ubuntu server to all my devices that are on the local network, I've created a folder in this directory `/home/my_user_name/Library`.
then I run `chmod 777 Library` to get access for all users, finally I've add to the smb.conf the following lines:

```
[Library]
    path = /home/my_user_folder/Library
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
    guest only = yes
```

then I've run:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

then I've tried to access from my windows machine, I can see the shared folder but when I'm clicking the folder I have a pop up message
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4ueG.png)

how I can get it to work?

also I've tried to access from my phone and I don't have permission

Comment: Looks like there are some good diagnostics in this web page. try those.
http://linux-training.be/networking/ch16.html

Comment: Is windows network connection on the private or public mode?

Comment: @A1Computers wants to know the following: "Is the Windows network connection on the private or public mode?" (you can verify that in a _Powershell_ window by executing the following command: `Get-NetConnectionProfile`)

Comment: Without release details, possible answers maybe incomplete or not work in your environment. Changes have occurred over time, thus there are differences in releases, so as you've not provided any release details - you'll need to adjust for your system yourself according to it's version.

Comment: I'm using Jammy release, my windows machine network connection is public, I can see the network but when I'm trying to coonnect it says i don't have permission

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping your server from your windows client?

Please run the following commands and paste the results-

```
ip -br a
sudo ufw status numbered
```

this is to verify if
a) your local ip is correct
b) your firewall is open to the samba ports windows is looking for

if the firewall is enabled, but Samba isn't on the list, try

```
sudo ufw allow Samba
```

This will open up the correct ports through your firewall.
Verify by running

```
sudo ufw status numbered
```

This will list all the current rules.
Then you can delete specific rules by entering the rule number.  for example:

```
sudo ufw delete 1
```

Let me know if this works

Comment: when I'm running `sudo ufw status numbered` I get `Status: inactive`, and when I'm tring to add the rule with `sudo ufw allow Samba` I'm getting:
`Skipping adding existing rule
Skipping adding existing rule (v6)`

Answer (score 0):

Change your share definition to this:

```
[Library]
    path = /home/my_user_name/Library
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
    force user = my_user_name
```

*Change my_user_name to an actual user name.*

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Don't have all the information necessary on how you are set up but it may be because you are using Ubuntu 22.04 or maybe your home directory is encrypted or ...